# Как сделать перенос строки по заданной позиции в строке

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать перенос строки на каждом *n'ом* символе? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```js
var str="You can communicate not only with friends, but also get acquainted with the mass of new interesting people.";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  document.write(str[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В цикл добавляем ещё одну переменную с учётом числа символа:

```js
var str="You can communicate not only with friends, but also get acquainted with the mass of new interesting people.";

var carry_option = {character_number: 4, carry_character: '<br>'}

for (var i = 0, n = 1; i < str.length; i++, n++){
  document.write(str[i]);
  
  // Если n = нашему числу, то переносим и обнуляем
  if( n == carry_option.character_number ){
    document.write( carry_option.carry_character );
    n = 0;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно разбить строку на кусочки с помощью `str.match(/.{1,N}/g)`

```js
var str="You can communicate not only with friends, but also get acquainted with the mass of new interesting people.";

var n = 8;
var r = new RegExp('.{1,'+n+'}', 'g')
var chunks = str.match(r)

//chunks.forEach(chunk => document.write(chunk+'<br />'));
document.write(chunks.join('<br />'))
```

Ну или можно просто воспользоваться оператором получения остатка от деления(`%`):

```js
var str="You can communicate not only with friends, but also get acquainted with the mass of new interesting people.";
var n = 8;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  document.write(str[i]);
  if ((i+1)%n == 0) document.write('<br/>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.match(/.{1,n}/g).join("\n")
```